# Categorial area stackplot in pandas grouped by date

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I found the way to implement the stackplot if my x-axis is just a list of numbers.

```
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplt as plt
d = {'time_key': {0: '2021-03-01',
  1: '2021-03-01',
  2: '2021-03-01',
  3: '2021-03-01'},
 'target': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 0, 3: 3},
 'count': {0: 400, 1: 300, 2: 200, 3: 100},
 'fraction': {0: 0.4, 1: 0.3, 2: 0.2, 3: 0.1}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
plt.stackplot(range(2), s[s.target==0].fraction, s[s.target==1].fraction,
          s[s.target==2].fraction, s[s.target==3].fraction)
```

[image]

But I want to generalize the plot to many dates list.

```
  d = {'time_key': {0: '2021-03-01',
  1: '2021-03-01',
  2: '2021-03-01',
  3: '2021-03-01',
  4: '2021-04-01',
  5: '2021-04-01',
  6: '2021-04-01',
  7: '2021-04-01',
  8: '2021-05-01',
  9: '2021-05-01',
  10: '2021-05-01',
  11: '2021-05-01'},
 'target': {0: 2,
  1: 1,
  2: 0,
  3: 3,
  4: 2,
  5: 1,
  6: 0,
  7: 3,
  8: 2,
  9: 1,
  10: 0,
  11: 3},
 'count': {0: 163,
  1: 110,
  2: 90,
  3: 38,
  4: 113,
  5: 97,
  6: 56,
  7: 34,
  8: 85,
  9: 57,
  10: 42,
  11: 16},
 'fraction': {0: 0.18091009988901222,
  1: 0.1220865704772475,
  2: 0.09988901220865705,
  3: 0.042175360710321866,
  4: 0.12541620421753608,
  5: 0.1076581576026637,
  6: 0.06215316315205328,
  7: 0.03773584905660377,
  8: 0.09433962264150944,
  9: 0.06326304106548279,
  10: 0.04661487236403995,
  11: 0.017758046614872364}}
```

And I'd like to assign dates to x-axis in ascending order to see dynamics of the proportions.
Is this a way to implement it in a proper way?

The approximate desired output plot (I need time_key x-axis though):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
dfp = df.set_index(['time_key','target'])['count'].unstack()
dfp.div(dfp.sum(axis=1), axis=0).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also useful solution is

```
d = {0: {'2021-03-01': 0.2, '2021-04-01': 0.25, '2021-05-01': 0.3},
 1: {'2021-03-01': 0.3, '2021-04-01': 0.25, '2021-05-01': 0.3},
 2: {'2021-03-01': 0.4, '2021-04-01': 0.25, '2021-05-01': 0.3},
 3: {'2021-03-01': 0.1, '2021-04-01': 0.25, '2021-05-01': 0.1}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 6))
plt.style.use('classic')
df.plot.area(ax=ax)
```

[image]